# Facebook sdk LikeView. How to ignore the installed Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I want to ignore official Facebook app when perform like/login/share actions as if the application is not installed.

For `ShareDialog` I can do this:

```
dialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.WEB);
```

But how can I forbid facebook app for the LikeView's following confirmation dialog (and login dialog, if not authorized)?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);
```